# How do you extract sentences containing one of a specified list of words followed by an adjective in Python

Tags: python, regex, nlp, regular-language, chunking

Want to extract all sentences containing a set of specified words followed by any adjective, e.g. "very good"

I tagged each word with its part of speech to recognize any adjective. Then, I specified the pattern using a regular expression. Here is the code:

```
import nltk
import os
import string
import re

s=["This","Movie","is","very","good"];
v=["extremely","very"];

tagged=nltk.pos_tag(s);

grammar= """Chunk: {[v[0]-v[4]]<JJ>}""";
parser=nltk.RegexpParser(grammar);
t=parser.parse(tagged);
```

But it didn't recognize the pattern I specified, no pair was labeled with "Chunk".

Comment: You could just convert the list to sets and use `.issubset()`? But that's just a crude approach